# How to group by one column but select last value

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

This is my database for messages
[image]

I want to group by receiver_id and this is my SQL

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id=2
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
GROUP BY receiver_id 
HAVING COUNT(receiver_id)>=1
```

It's working but it always shows subject `Bok` and `created_at=2013-08-19 20:49:22`
I would like to show latest created_at and subject, in this example `2013-08-20 14:29:41`

This is my output

[image]

Comment: Do you need only one record i.e only latest record

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
         m1.* 
FROM 
         messages m1 
LEFT JOIN 
         messages m2
ON 
    (m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id 
     AND m1.created_at < m2.created_at)
WHERE 
    m2.created_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupwise maximum has helped me http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html
So my query looks like

`...WHERE created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at FROM mg_messages t2 WHERE t.receiver_id=t2.receiver_id)...`